# Summing a column by an id in Teradata SQL

Tags: sql, teradata

Right now I have the following output from the following code... (an id can have only 1 code but a code can have many ids)

```
SEL a.id, a.code,
CASE WHEN f.fac_id = 80007944 THEN 1
                WHEN f.fac_id = 80007838 THEN 1
                WHEN f.fac_id = 80007998 THEN 1 
                WHEN f.fac_id = 80007823 THEN 1
                END AS Count1
FROM db1.t1 a
INNER JOIN db2.t2 f ON f.fac_id = a.fac_id
AND a.code IN (060, 140)
ORDER BY a.code

id  code    Count1
CFC 060     1
CFC 060     1
CFC 060     1
CFC 060     1
CFC 060     1
CFC 060     1
CFC 060     1
CFC 060     1
CFC 060     1
FAD 140     1
FAD 140     1
FAD 140     1
FAD 140     1
FAD 140     1
FAD 140     1
E5C 140     1
E5C 140     1
E5C 140     1
915 140     1
915 140     1
915 140     1
6AD 140     1
6AD 140     1
6AD 140     1
6AD 140     1
6AD 140     1
6AD 140     1
```

I'm wanting to create a new column that shows the sum of count1 by id. Can anyone help me modify my code to reflect that? Here's an example of my desired output...

```
id  code    Count1  count_per_id
CFC 060     1       9
CFC 060     1       9
CFC 060     1       9
CFC 060     1       9
CFC 060     1       9
CFC 060     1       9
CFC 060     1       9
CFC 060     1       9
CFC 060     1       9
FAD 140     1       6
FAD 140     1       6
FAD 140     1       6
FAD 140     1       6
FAD 140     1       6
FAD 140     1       6
E5C 140     1       3
E5C 140     1       3
E5C 140     1       3
915 140     1       3
915 140     1       3
915 140     1       3
6AD 140     1       6
6AD 140     1       6
6AD 140     1       6
6AD 140     1       6
6AD 140     1       6
6AD 140     1       6
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a window function:

```
SELECT a.id, a.code,
       (CASE WHEN f.fac_id IN (80007944, 80007838, 80007998, 80007823 THEN 1
        END) AS Count1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN f.fac_id IN (80007944, 80007838, 80007998, 80007823 THEN 1
           END) OVER (PARTITION BY id)
FROM db1.t1 a INNER JOIN
     db2.t2 f ON f.fac_id = a.fac_id AND a.code IN (060, 140)
ORDER BY a.code
```

Comment: Ahh repeating the case statement that's a good idea. Do we not also want to partition by `a.code`?

Comment: Since this is Teradata, you can just sum using the alias - `sum(count1) over (partition by id)`.  Works the same, less typing...

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was don't we want to include both `id` and `code` in the windowed function? My assumption here is that there is a reason they are not `grouped` in Justin B's example.

Comment: @Edward, based on your example, it looks like the `code` is the same for each `id`.

Comment: Yes I suppose OP does say that an `id` can only have a single `code`. I'll amend my answer to remove `inner.code` from my window.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT inner.id , inner.code , inner.Count1 , sum(Count1) Over (partition by inner.id)
FROM ( 
SEL a.id as id, a.code as code
CASE WHEN f.fac_id = 80007944 THEN 1
                WHEN f.fac_id = 80007838 THEN 1
                WHEN f.fac_id = 80007998 THEN 1 
                WHEN f.fac_id = 80007823 THEN 1
                END AS Count1
FROM db1.t1 a
INNER JOIN db2.t2 f ON f.fac_id = a.fac_id
AND a.code IN (060, 140)
) AS inner 
ORDER BY inner.code
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using an inner join on subquery with sum group by id and code

```
select  a.id, a.code, t count1 
FROM db1.t1 a
INNER JOIN db2.t2 f ON f.fac_id = a.fac_id AND a.code IN (060, 140)
INNER JOIN (
SELECT  a.id, a.code,
sum(CASE WHEN f.fac_id = 80007944 THEN 1
                WHEN f.fac_id = 80007838 THEN 1
                WHEN f.fac_id = 80007998 THEN 1 
                WHEN f.fac_id = 80007823 THEN 1
                ELSE 0
                END) AS Count1
FROM db1.t1 a
INNER JOIN db2.t2 f ON f.fac_id = a.fac_id
AND a.code IN (060, 140)
GROUP BY a.id, a.code
) t on t.id = a.id and t.code = a.code 
ORDER BY a.code
```